# Advice sought on obsolete application in Django

Tags: django

We have a Django app without any content now (we have moved the models to another app), and the only thing left is the migrations
I tried removing the migrations, however we have migrations in other apps that have dependancies on the app we wish to remove
Is there any advice / guidance on removing apps in Django?